# How do I group by _id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I am using the aggregation framework. So far so good.

```
conn = Mongo::Connection.new
db   = conn['foobar_development']

cmd = {
  aggregate: 'live_daily_stats',
  pipeline: [
    # { '$match' => { :_id => "20120725/foobar/song/custom-cred" } },
    { '$project' => {
      :visits => 1,
    } },
    { '$unwind' => '$visits' },
    # { '$group' => {
    #   :_id => '$_id'
    # } },
    { '$match' => { 'visits.minute' => { '$gt' => 224 } } },
    { '$sort' => { 'visits.minute' => 1 } },
    # { '$group' => { :_id => '$_id' } },
  ]
}

res = db.command(cmd)['result']
```

`results` returns the following below. As you can see, there are 4 results. That fall under two `_ids`. How do I group the `visits` under those `_ids`?

```
[
    [0] {
           "_id" => "20120725/foobar/song/custom-cred",
        "visits" => {
                                          "country_name" => "UK",
                           "iso_two_letter_country_code" => "UK",
                                               "referer" => "http://localhost:3000/cfazzini/songs/custom-cred",
                                                "minute" => 251,
                                              "token_id" => "134318948211lzyqexgo"
        }
    },
    [1] {
           "_id" => "20120725/foobar/song/custom-cred",
        "visits" => {
                                          "country_name" => "UK",
                           "iso_two_letter_country_code" => "UK",
                                               "referer" => "http://localhost:3000/cfazzini/songs/custom-cred",
                                                "minute" => 1118,
                                              "token_id" => "134324148411hsrxvakn"
        }
    },
    [2] {
           "_id" => "20120725/foobar/song/test-pg3-long-title-here-test-lorem-ipsum-dolor-lo",
        "visits" => {
                                          "country_name" => "UK",
                           "iso_two_letter_country_code" => "UK",
                                               "referer" => "http://localhost:3000/",
                                                "minute" => 1121,
                                              "token_id" => "13432416893tlfsmmgh"
        }
    },
    [3] {
           "_id" => "20120725/foobar/song/custom-cred",
        "visits" => {
                                          "country_name" => "UK",
                           "iso_two_letter_country_code" => "UK",
                                               "referer" => "http://localhost:3000/",
                                                "minute" => 1121,
                                              "token_id" => "134324169011hmtkxrgt"
        }
    }
]
```

Second, how can I run the same command using a rails model, without having to define `conn` and `db`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to use the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_push) operator - something like:

```
cmd = {
  aggregate: 'live_daily_stats',
  pipeline: [
    { '$project' => {
        :visits => 1,
      }
    },
    { '$unwind' => '$visits' },
    { '$match' => { 'visits.minute' => { '$gt' => 224 } } },
    { '$sort' => { 'visits.minute' => 1 } },
    { '$group' => { :_id => '$_id', 
                    :visits => { '$push' => '$visits' }},
    }
  ]
}
```

2) You can grab the connection like so: `Mongoid.database.connection` rather than having to define db and connection.  The aggregate helper is coming soon - currently in progress.  Follow this ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-455

Comment: Missing a `}`. Other than that. Great, that works! Any ideas on my second question?

Comment: What library are you using?  Mongoid or mongomapper?

Comment: Using Mongoid, but shouldn't it be possible using the MongoDb Ruby driver directly? Something like: `LiveDailyStat.collection.aggregate(`. I know update can be used as `LiveDailyStat.collection.update(`. Not sure if Mongoid supports the Aggregation Framework just yet, since its still in development

Comment: Updated the answer - its on its way!

Comment: One more thing, how would one sort the grouped `_id`s based on how many visits there are for that id? Do I need to append a second `$sort` to the pipeline?

Comment: You dont want much! - yeah in the group add a $sum like: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_group and then add a final $sort.

Comment: `{ '$group' => { :_id => '$_id', :visits => { '$push' => '$visits' }, :visits_count => { '$sum' => '$visits' } } },` seems to throw an error: `Mongo::OperationFailure: Database command 'aggregate' failed: (errmsg: 'exception: can't convert from BSON type Object to double'; code: '16005'; ok: '0.0').` Any idea why?

Comment: Ok `{ '$group' => { :_id => '$_id', :visits => { '$push' => '$visits' }, :visits_count => { '$sum' => 1 } } }, { '$sort' => { 'visits_count' => -1 } },` works! Thanks!